# Retrieving data from google api and get 403 error

Tags: javascript, google-analytics-api

I am trying to use google API in my application but it gives me 403 error I am using, and the error said that this account doesn't have google analytics account but it have

JS Code:

```
 var VIEW_ID = '67520075'
function queryReports() {
gapi.client.request({
  path: '/v4/reports:batchGet',
  root: 'https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/',
  method: 'POST',
  body: {
    reportRequests: [
      {
        viewId: VIEW_ID,
        dateRanges: [
          {
            startDate: '7daysAgo',
            endDate: 'today'
          }
        ],
        metrics: [
          {
            expression: 'ga:sessions'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}).then(displayResults, console.error.bind(console));
}
function displayResults(response) {
var formattedJson = JSON.stringify(response.result, null, 2);
document.getElementById('query-output').value = formattedJson;
```

}

The error that returns :

[image]

Comment: Have you enabled the google analytics API on your google account ?

Comment: i enabled google analytics reporting api from console developer is that what u mean ?

Comment: The account that you have used during authorization i.e. xyz@gmail.com does not have any Google Analytics account.